# Reparameterization trick for exponential distribution

Tags: autoencoders, variational-bayes

Is there way to generate Exponential(lambda) distributed samples via a reparameterization trick?

As in: [Reparameterization trick for gamma distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368194/reparameterization-trick-for-gamma-distribution)

And also: [How does the reparameterization trick for VAEs work and why is it important?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199605/how-does-the-reparameterization-trick-for-vaes-work-and-why-is-it-important)

My motivation is to compare Exponential priors with Normal priors, in a neural network, having the latter solved as per the second link.

Though I have no experience in this field (and a general understanding), I am coding a project in MXNet where I compare different architectures in terms of predictive accuracy on IHDP data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can generate an exponential rv. with rate 1 (call this X), then you can generate an exponential random variable with rate lambda by multiplying X with 1/lambda.

So, if you want to use an exponential function as a posterior, you can use the re-parametrization trick in variational autoencoders by only generating exponential rv. with rate 1.